# Parameter substitution and error messages: suppressing line numbers etc

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, parameter

Here is my example file:

```
!/bin/bash
# argument-one

# Is first argument missing?

# First method
[[ "$1" == "" ]] && echo "Usage: $(basename $0) filename"; exit 1

# Second method
# filename=${1?"Usage: $(basename $0) filename"}
```

In the above script, I get a "clean" message

`Usage: argument-one filename`

when I run the above script with no arguments; and it exits cleanly.

However, if I comment out line 7 and uncomment line 10, I get this error message when the program exits:

`./argument-one: line 10: 5: Usage: argument-one filename`

This message suggests that there is something wrong with the program that triggered it to exit, when in fact, it was actually an invocation with no arguments, which is a usage issue.

But line 10 is preferable because it is more terse and also assigns a variable if available.

My question is: "How might I retain only the message part and filter out or disable the `./argument-one: line 10: 5:` part of the usage message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$#` special variable, to test the number of arguments given to a command:

```sh
usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 arg"
  exit 1
}

if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
  usage
fi

echo "called with $1"
exit 0
```

When executed, this scripts gives:

```
$ ./foo.sh
Usage: ./foo.sh arg

$ ./foo.sh bar
called with bar
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know how to suppress the first part of the output when used with the **second** method in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter substitution to do the assignment, but catch the error and change it:

```
filename=$((printf "${1:?}") 2>/dev/null || { echo "Usage $(basename $0) filename"; exit 1; })
```

(`printf` could be `echo` for fewer characters but an extra fork). Note that the printf/echo is in its own subshell, and its actually the subshell's stderr that is being piped to /dev/null.

Alternatively, you can just test that the variable after assignment using parameter substitution is set and non-blank, then print your usage string and exit manually (one one line):

```
[ -z "${filename:=$1}" ] && { echo "Usage $(basename $0) filename"; exit 1; }
```

I tend to go with the second option because it is fewer characters, more obvious/straightforward, and does less rework. The one downside is that if filename was already set in your env, $1 wont be used. If you are worried about that, just `unset filename` beforehand.